# How to display images from the gallery of the current product in the preview?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

everyone!

Maybe somebody know, how to display images from the gallery of the current product (.product) on the catalog page (.products) as a preview of all images? At the moment, on the catalog page, i can to display images only for the first product.

I would be grateful for any information!

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'add_custom_flipper_img', 30);

function add_custom_flipper_img() {
    global $product;
    $attachment_ids = $product->get_gallery_attachment_ids();
    
    foreach( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id, 'thumbnail');
    }
}
```